# Behavioral difference between enyo.dispatch(e) and target.dispatchEvent(e) web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, enyo

I am curious to know that how dispatch of event happens in Enyo. Say for a, simple DOM tree, having a parent node with two child nodes. All i want to do is to propagate custom event generated from child 1 to child 2. I have created a sample for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/hfh3z2q4/

```
enyo.kind({
name: "MySample",
kind: "moon.Panels",
classes: "moon",
pattern:"activity",
components: [{kind: "moon.Panel", 
title: "Hello World!",headerComponents: [
{kind: "moon.IconButton", src: "assets/icon-like.png"}
], 
components: [
{kind: "moon.Input",placeholder: "type time",onchange :"handleInput"},
{kind:"ClockSample", name:'time'}
]}
],
handleInput: function(inSender, inEvent) {
    // body...
    var val=inSender.getValue();
    var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
    evt.initEvent("myEvent",true,true);
    evt.val=val;
    var target=this.$.time.hasNode();
    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
    //enyo.dispatcher.dispatch(evt);
}
});
enyo.kind({
name: "ClockSample",
components: [
    {kind: "moon.Clock", name:"clock"}
],
create:function(){
    this.inherited(arguments);
    enyo.dispatcher.listen(document, "myEvent",  this.bindSafely(this.myEventHandler));
},
myEventHandler: function(inSender, inEvent) {
    // body...
    this.$.clock.setDate(new Date(inSender.val));
}
});


new MySample({fit:true}).renderInto(document.body);
```

If i try to use "target.dispatchEvent(evt)", and type the expected date format (i.e. Jan 01 2015 09:08:07), the clock time will set to the same, but the behavior is not similiar when try to use "enyo.dispatcher.dispatch(evt)".

Please help me to know the differences and enyo way of achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying 'Don't do that!'.  This is not the correct way to handle this type of problem.  If you really must send messages like this between objects use signals.  To attempt to send messages between siblings breaks encapsulation.

Second, Enyo's normal events aren't DOM events.  If you want to create events on objects to listen for you should declare an `events` block with your events, as described here:  [Event Handling](http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/key-concepts/event-handling.html). You've gone down the DOM event route, which I don't recommend. If you do want to use DOM events, then use the `dispatchEvent()` method you've already taken.

Third, when using Moonstone, only select Dark or Light, not both.  Moonstone requires the use of the Spotlight library, as well.

Finally, using `dispatcher.dispatch()` bypasses the dom event registration you did with `listen()`.  You can overcome that using signals and listening for the custom event.  But really, just use pure signals.  Try this fiddle for the first (less ideal) approach: http://jsfiddle.net/hfh3z2q4/1/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info. I got the intention that it is very much needed to preserve encapsulation/data hiding. But i am not sure how using signals or bubbling event up the DOM tree helps in sustaining data encapsulation. May you explain more on that..

Comment: The signals mechanism is a broadcast message that subscribers can subscribe to.  It's better than the bubbling mechanism because you don't have to know where to bubble a message and it only goes to subscribers.

Comment: @Pre101 Hi, the jsfiddle is not working anymore... do you maybe have a working example? I know it is from a few years ago, but I can't manage to make signals work now....